# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebEngineWidgets

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I want to make a simple program using a website, based on this code::

[GitHub](https://github.com/AgnerSecurity/Agner-Browser/blob/main/C%C3%B3digo%20em%20Python%20PT-BR/main.py)

but pressing 'run' without modifying anything of the code I get this error:

```
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebEngineWidgets: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have already installed: [image]